# how to dynamically move list items inside a DIV to get proper arrangement?

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I have a some images displayed using list items inside a div. With simple CSS float:left tricks, I am able to get the following layout:
[image: current]

But I was them to dynamically arrange based on div width and height and want something like this:
[image: wished]

Let me know if there is any way to achieve the same using CSS, JavaScript or jQuery.

Also, let me know if these sample screenshots does not help and HTML code is needed.

Thanks

EDIT: Adding image after applying masonry plugin (see image 3 below). Now I have equal number of images and they are equally spaced and with proper gutter. But it is always aligned to left. How can this always be centered aligned?

I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="" class="myimage">
    <img src="" class="myimage">
    <img src="" class="myimage">
    <img src="" class="myimage">
</div>
```

And jQuery for masonry part:

$('#container').masonry({
    "gutter": 10,
    itemSelector: '.myimage'
});

[image]

EDIT 2: Also made a jsfiddle to show the problem with right margin after applying masonry plugin. Please resize browser also to see right gap in each case: http://jsfiddle.net/5KyRd/7/

Comment: just make the boxes wider?

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ might be of help. You won't make it with HTML or CSS alone (as far as I know at least).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://sapegin.github.io/jquery.mosaicflow/

Comment: Are you attempting to fill a div `evenly` with images in which the div has a predefined width and height?  Do **all** the images have a set width and height so they'll never change?

Comment: What back end language, if any, are you using? i.e. PHP, ASP, Ruby

Comment: @AmazingDreams and Monkey Thanks.. Let  me try the masonry and mosaic plugins.

Comment: @hungerstar yes, I am trying to fill div evenly with images. DIV has a span11 width of bootstrap and all images are of same height and width of 125x50px.

I am using ASP.NET but no server controls are used. Its all pure HTML and I use Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: @AmazingDreams your Masonry option really helped me. But still there is 1 issue. It always aligns to the left and some space is always there on the right side. I am adding another image to display this issue.

Comment: Are you willing to use CSS3 media queries and a polyfill for older borwsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **media query** solution: http://jsfiddle.net/B45qv/

First you'll set your images to be `max-width: 100%` so they'll be flexible.

From there you will need to decide how many images you want per row and set their width as a percentage.  That's as simple as dividing 100 by the number per row ( 100 / 7 = 14.285714% ).  This width should include all padding and margins as they will add to the image's dimensions.

For a 1% margin on all sides the width for the image above would be 12.285714%, `1 + 12.285714% + 1 = 14.285714%`.

Other than that you just need to decide at what screen dimensions you will adjust the number per row.  My example had arbitrary values.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/50/" alt="temp" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
div {
    width: 86%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
div img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 12.285714%;  /* 7 per row */
    margin: 1%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    /* 6 per row */
    div img {
        width: 14.66666%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
    /* 5 per row */
    div img {
        width: 18%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    /* 4 per row */
    div img {
        width: 23%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    /* 3 per row */
    div img {
        width: 31.33333%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    /* 2 per row */
    div img {
        width: 48%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS3 property calc.

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width:600px;
}
img{
    width:calc(600px / 4);
}
```

It's supported in all major web browsers, desktop and mobile. You won't get support in older browsers of course, but It's extremely useful in responsive/fluid layouts. I use it often.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, it doesn't work on the default Android browser, unfortunately, but that's not stopping me from using it for the desktop versions of my sites.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know what would be the width of div in fluid layout. And when the width decreases, we need a way to find out how many images can be pushed in a single row and then find its width.

Comment: As for the width of the div, width:100%; and then calc(100% / 4); If you want them to move to columns of 3 after a certain point, you could do so with media queries. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question. I could be totally off.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the container by using `display:table`

```
#container {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not making any difference.

Comment: This is how you would center a div without a given width, eg for fluid layout. If it isn't centering your div then there is another issue at hand DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5KyRd/

Comment: I have updated your demo with my code. You can see that there is a right margin after applying masonry plugin. Please resize browser also to see right gap in each case: http://jsfiddle.net/5KyRd/7/